# How to fetch rows that don't match where condition in a query using sum

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT k.condition, 
       SUM(IIf(AnimalType=3,1,0)) AS Carnivore, 
       SUM(IIf(AnimalType=4,1,0)) as Herbivore
From Animals a inner join knownconditions k on a.id = k.id
where a.id in (3, 11, 12)
AND (AnimalType=3 OR AnimalType = 4)
Group by a.id, k.id
```

The above query brings all Animals which have a specific Type of condition. Like this:

```
Condition   | Carnivore | Herbivore
------------| ----------|-------------
Condition1  | 33        | 3
Condition2  | 2         | 4
```

For the sake of this example, consider that there is a record in `knownconditions` table such as below

```
ID    | Condition
------|------------
3     | Condition3
```

Luckily no animal in `Animals` table has condition `Condition3`. Therefore, my query above does not even list `Condition3`.

How can I modify my query so that the results brought are:

```
Condition   | Carnivore | Herbivore
------------| ----------|-------------
Condition1  | 33        | 3
Condition2  | 2         | 4
Condition3  | 0         | 0
```

Comment: Could you post your table definitions? It's a bit tough to figure out with just that. Thanks.

Comment: I would love to but the actual tables are much bigger and complex. That's why I came up with design that pin points my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different approach using literals and a union:

```
SELECT condition, SUM(Carnivore), SUM(Herbivore)
FROM
(
    SELECT k.condition, 
       SUM(IIf(AnimalType=3,1,0)) AS Carnivore, 
       SUM(IIf(AnimalType=4,1,0)) as Herbivore
    From Animals a inner join knownconditions k on a.id = k.id
    where a.id in (3, 11, 12)
    AND (AnimalType=3 OR AnimalType = 4)
    Group by k.condition, a.id, k.id
    UNION
    SELECT condition, 0, 0
    From knownconditions
)
GROUP BY condition
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to an outer join:

```
SELECT k.condition,  
   SUM(IIf(AnimalType=3,1,0)) AS Carnivore,  
   SUM(IIf(AnimalType=4,1,0)) as Herbivore 
From knownconditions k 
  Left join Animals a  
      on a.id = k.id 
         And a.id in (3, 11, 12) 
         And AnimalType In (3, 4) 
Group by k.id, a.id
```

This will produce all conditions in knownConditions, and, for each of the animal types, the total number of records in knownconditions that has each condition.

Comment: That still doesn't work. I had read up on outer joins and given it a try but it did not work. I just want to assert the point again that Animal table does not contain ID 3 at all

Answer (score 0):

Take left join as Animals Vs. knownconditions. So that animals will be counted according to condition. If condition not satisfies then it will return 0.

```
SELECT k.condition, 
       SUM(IIf(AnimalType=3,1,0)) AS Carnivore, 
       SUM(IIf(AnimalType=4,1,0)) as Herbivore
From Animals a LEFT JOIN knownconditions k on a.id = k.id
AND a.id in (3, 11, 12)
AND (AnimalType=3 OR AnimalType = 4 ) 
Group by a.id, k.id
```

Please comment if working. I havn't tested it.